# How can I store data from Symfony formbuilder into an Array?

Tags: arrays, json, symfony, formbuilder

I am creating a form with formbuilder:

```
$formBuilder->add($fieldMapping['fieldName'], TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')), 'required' => 'true');
```

When I am saving the form I am able to store the data from the form into an array:

```
  $('.create-item').on( 'click', function (e) {
      forms(e,this);
    });


function forms(e,el) {

  var id = $(el).attr("data-id");
  var target = $(el).attr("data-target");

  e.preventDefault();
  var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
  $.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    data: {
      "id": id,
      "target": target
    },
    url: $link.attr('href')
  }).done(function(data){
    $('.form-output').html(data.output);
    $('#form_save').on( 'click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this).closest('form');
      var formData = form.serializeArray();


      $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:'{{ path('forms', { 'slug': page.slug }) }}',
        data: {
          "data": formData
        },
        success: function(data){
          window.location.reload();
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

So the output of the variable `formData` is:

```
[
    {name:"form[id]", value:""}, 
    {name:"form[username]", value:""}, 
    {name:"form[plainPassword]", value:""}, 
    {name:"form[email]", value:""}, 
    {name:"form[isActive]", value:"1"}, 
    {name:"form[_token]", value:"123414234"}]
```

The information I would also need in this array is if "required = true". Is there a chance to add this to the array?

Comment: why you would like to retreive that info in the client side while you have it in the server side ?

Comment: I do not have access to it on the server side